# Setting styles for subcontrols of usercontrol

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

Say I have a user control like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="StyleTest.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0">Style please</Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1">Style please</Button>
</Grid>
```

And I want to set all buttons in this control to background=green.
But I don't want to affect other buttons in my program and I don't want to modify the code of the control.

What I found right now is this:

```
<Window x:Class="StyleTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:StyleTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="UserControlStyles" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="green" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0">no Style please</Button>
    <loc:UserControl1 Grid.Column="1">
        <loc:UserControl1.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource UserControlStyles}" />
        </loc:UserControl1.Resources>
    </loc:UserControl1>
</Grid>
```

But this would imply that I have to add this code to every instance of the control, and some extra code, if I want to style e.g. foreground color of TextBoxes also.

What I am looking for is something similar to this:

```
        <Style TargetType="Buttons that are childs of UserControl1">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="green" />
    </Style>
```

Is there a way of doing this?

I don't think that a control template would be sufficient, because I don't want to redesign the whole control, I just want to set the color of the buttons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In App.xaml you could add this style which will be applied to all instances of UserControl1

```
<Style TargetType="StyleTest:UserControl1" >
   <Style.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="green" />
     </Style>
   </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you just need to modify your UserControl so that you add the style there, instead of in the Window control

```
<UserControl x:Name=UserControl1 ...>
<UserControl.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="green" />
   </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I just saw that you said you don't want to modify the control. You mean that you can't modify the xaml of the UserControl? Why not?

Comment: This is more or less, what I'm doing now. But I don't want to add this code to every usage of this control. I want to have a central place (app.xaml) to set the style for all buttons in all controls of this type.

Comment: @MTR: This isn't to every usage of the control, just inside the control definition.

Comment: I see. But I don't want to modify the code of the control, because it is used by other programs.